# code.google.com: amount of SVN disk space used

Tags: svn, google-code

If I am the admin of a project hosted at code.google.com (in this case http://code.google.com/p/o2platform/) where can I find how much SVN space I am using? and how much do I still have left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the Source Tab. Disk space used is on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, just realized that the answer is the page checkout page (http://code.google.com/p/o2platform/source/checkout), in this case:

"This project is currently using approximately 164 MB (16.0%) of its 1024 MB repository quota."

Comment: And you can always request more space. Just post a mail to the support group and you'll have your quota increased withing a day or two.